# Read files into a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

**What am I doing wrong when I am trying to read these into a dictionary?**

I am getting this error when trying to read values into a dictionary:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#27>", line 1, in <module>
    ListAllFiles()
  File "C:\Python27\1.py", line 14, in ListAllFiles
    (key, val) = line.split('=')
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I am using this code to open every text file in the directory and read its contents into a dictionary:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import glob
import os

# Let's read all the files into the set
def ListAllFiles():
    mydir="C:\\Python27"
    os.chdir(mydir)
    for file in glob.glob("*.txt"):
        #print(mydir+'\\'+file)
        d = {}
        with open(mydir+'\\'+file) as f:
            for line in f:
               (key, val) = line.split('=')
               d[file] = (key,val)
               print (val)
```

an example of one of the text files is:

```
paramA=Y
paramB=30
paramC=normal
paramD=SOME_ITEM_IN_ALL_CAPS
paramE=5 6 7 8 9 
paramF=/dir/to/stuff
paramG=y
```

I would like the dictionary to look like this:

```
+-----------+--------+-----------------------+
| filename1 | paramA | Y                     |
| filename1 | paramB | 30                    |
| filename1 | paramC | normal                |
| filename1 | paramD | SOME_ITEM_IN_ALL_CAPS |
| filename1 | paramE | 5 6 7 8 9             |
| filename1 | paramF | /dir/to/stuff         |
| filename1 | paramG | y                     |
| Filename2 | paramA | A                     |
| Filename2 | paramB | 22                    |
| Filename2 | paramC | st                    |
| Filename2 | paramD | AAAA                  |
| Filename2 | paramE | 5 6 7 8 9             |
| Filename2 | paramF | ff                    |
| Filename2 | paramG | g                     |
| Filename3 | etc    | etc                   |
+-----------+--------+-----------------------+
```

I would imagine the dictionary would be something like this:

```
d={filename1:(ParamA='A', ParamB='22', Paramc='st'....),filename2:(paramA=...
```

**What am I doing wrong when I am trying to read these into a dictionary?**

Comment: You're encountering a line that doesn't contain a `=` character, so `split('=')` returns only one value.

Comment: Can you `print(line)`? I suspect that there is a header (or some other line) that does not have a `'='`.

Comment: Apart from number of `=` symbols issue you're replacing the value of same key again and again, better initialize `d[file] = {}` before you loop over a file and then inside of the loop do `d[file][key] = val`.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary cool! can you please make that into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You most probably have an empty line in one of the files.

Protect that part of the code with a `if line:`, or a `try`...`except`