# adding a list to a dictionary in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

**How do I add a list to a dictionary?**

i have a dictionary:

```
>>> data = {}
>>> myfile='file.txt'
>>> data.update({myfile:['parama','y']})
>>> data
{'file.txt': ['parama', 'y']}
```

I would like to add to the key 'file.txt' another touple, such that the result would be

```
{'file.txt': (['parama', 'y'],['paramb','abc'])}
```

I tried to update this specific key like this:

```
data['file.txt'].update(['paramb','abc'])
```

but got an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#51>", line 1, in <module>
    data['file.txt'].update(['paramb', 'y'])
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'update'
>>>
```

**How do I add a list to a dictionary?**

Comment: that's not a tuple you're trying to add, it's a list...

Comment: First, `update` is a method on dicts, not on lists, and `data['file.txt']` is a list.

Comment: Second, there's no method that can convert a single list into a tuple of two lists. You can do _replace_ a list with a tuple of two lists, something like `data['file.txt'] = (data['file.txt'], ['paramb','abc'])`, but it's hard to imagine a case where that line would be the best way to write anything… If you can explain what you're actually trying to do here, it might help.

Comment: If you need to mutate things, then you shouldn't be using tuples as they are immutable. If you keep it as a list, as the value is now, is `append` so bad? You end up with a list of lists.

Comment: im reading files into 1 dictionary: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918211/read-files-into-a-dictionary-in-python  and i want the result to be file1, parama, 'some text', then next line file2, parama, "other text" etc

Comment: @nerdwaller: Yeah, I *think* what he actually wants to do is start with a list of one list, and then `append` the second list to that. But… it's hard to be sure.

Comment: @nerdwaller i think you are exactly right!! that is what i need

Comment: OK, from that other question, it looks like you either want a dict of dicts, or a dict with 2-tuples as keys, not a dict of either tuples or lists of lists.

Comment: i think i got it? http://screencast.com/t/QCYgARqi

Comment: can this still be considered a dictionary though? {'file.txt': ['parama', 'y', ['paramb', 'y']]}

Comment: @abarnert - good call, it's definitely odd. Seems like the right approach is to start with the correct structure and build it out instead of changing the structure. Changing it will make some pretty annoying code to read.

Comment: Well, that's a dictionary whose values are lists, but that doesn't seem particularly useful.

Comment: @nerdwaller i agree, but the structure is dynamic, it will change over time

Comment: @abarnert would you pick a different datatype for such a problem?

Comment: It might help to write the code you'd like to use to _access_ these values after you've built the data structure. Do you want to be able to write `d['file.txt']['parama']` and get `'y'`? Or `d['file.txt', 'parama']`?

Comment: @abarnert EXCELLENT question. thank you for asking it. i would like to be able to get ALL 3 values, the key, and each element inside of the list (values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're after here is a dictionary whose keys are filenames, and whose values are themselves dictionaries whose keys are parameter names. Like this:

```
d = {
    'filename1': {
        'parama': 'A',
        'paramb': '22' },
    'filename2': {
        'parama': 'Z'}
}
```

This would allow you to access values like this:

```
>>> d['filename1']['parama']
'A'
```

And if you want to get all the parameters for `filename1`:

```
>>> d['filename1']
{'parama': 'A', 'paramb': '22'}
>>> for k, v in d['filename1'].items():
...     print('{}: {}'.format(k, v))
parama: A
paramb: 22
```

---

If so, you're going wrote before you've gotten to the point you're asking about. Instead of this:

```
data.update({myfile:['parama','y']})
```

… you want:

```
data[myfile]['parama'] = 'y'
```

However, there's one slight problem here. If this is the first time you've seen a parameter for `myfile`, there is no `data[myfile]` yet. To solve that, you can use the `setdefault` method:

```
data.setdefault(myfile, {})['parama'] = 'y'
```

Or you can make `data` a `collections.defaultdict(dict)` instead of a plain `dict`.